# Nginx rewrite rule with repeated pattern to convert filename to a bunch of folders based on the filename

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm making a website kind of like imgur.com that hosts lots of images from the root of the URL, i.e. i.example.com/imagefile.jpg

But I want to split the files up on the server into multiple folders to avoid having too many files in one folder (to avoid filesystem performance issues).  I'd like each folder names to consist of 2 alphanumeric (A-Za-z0-9) characters from the filename, recursively.

Is there a single rewrite rule that can do this using a repeated pattern?

Some examples of the resulting rewrites would be:

```
/1.jpg >>> /1/1.jpg
/ab.jpg >>> /ab/ab.jpg
/abc.jpg >>> /ab/c/abc.jpg
/abcd.jpg >>> /ab/cd/abcd.jpg
/filename.jpg >>> /fi/le/na/me/filename.jpg
```

The URLs will also sometimes contains dashes/hyphens, which I'd like ignored for the folders, but kept in the filename.  i.e:

```
/this-has-dashes.jpg >>> /th/is/ha/sd/as/he/s/this-has-dashes.jpg
```

Is this possible with a single rule?  That would be great.  But if not, I'd be happy to write multiple rules for the various expected lengths of the filenames.